# Extracting the td value from inner html when there is also a SPAN

Tags: javascript, dom, html-table

I can't seem to quite figure this out, I am attempting to extract the TD value, I suppose everything works just as good as it should, but since I have also span in between the TD's, its extracts everything in it. How do I chop out the span, maybe a regex expression or something?

```
document.getElementById('ID').value = row.cells[0].innerHTML
```

gives me this:

```
<SPAN style="WHITE-SPACE: nowrap;">XAI-2013-411041</SPAN>
```

Here is the original HTML markup of the TD:

```
<td><span style="white-space: nowrap;">XAI-2013-411041</span></td>
```

The only piece of data that I want is the

```
XAI-2013-411041
```

Comment: i'd like to try and stay away from any libraries

Comment: document.getElementById('ID').value.split(">")[1].split("<")[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just do this:

```
row.cells[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML;
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Wow...lots of ways here to skin a cat. I just went with this one because it uses less and is clean and fast. The span is just there because IE7 doesn't respect the whitespace nowrap on a td.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('ID').value.split(">")[1].split("<")[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score -1):

If all the td tags are written in this format, you could simply use the ID of the span tag by setting cells[0] to spanID:

```
rows.cells[0] = "row0col0";
document.getElementById('ID').value = row.cells[0].innerHTML;
```

Using this as your HTML:

```
<TD><SPAN style="..." id=row0col0>...</SPAN></TD>
```